# Is it possible to make dynamic permission management of a group per view?

Tags: django, django-views

For example I have a view called Article and I have groups called Author and Reader. And I want to o set to the author permissions to get and post to the Article view, and set permission only get to the Reader group. Also I want to add or remove any permission from any group to any Views from Django dashboard.

I have already seen Django group permissions for the dashboard only, but I want to extent this feature to any view independently if the view is a rest view or MVC view.

Comment: This is super possible with django and one aspect where django starts to shine! Your question is quite broad. You might get better help with a more precise question. Maybe this helps you: The [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator allows you to check for user permission or group permission before the functionality of the view gets activated. Feel free to edit your question to a more specific case with code example to get better support.

Comment: Ohh, I probably read this page, but somehow omitted the user_passes_test. And I think this function suits to my current problem. So, thank you for the guidance.